# Finding parameters values given the solution with two non-linear equations in R

Tags: r

I have two equations which describe the moments (mean and variance) of the truncated Gaussian distribution. I built the following function to compute them:

```
trunc_moments <- function(moments, a, b){

  require(truncnorm)

  mu <- moments[1]
  sigma <- moments[2]

  alpha <- (a - mu) / sigma; beta <- (b - mu) / sigma

  mu_trunc <- mu + sigma*
    ((dnorm(alpha, mu, sigma) - dnorm(beta, mu, sigma)) /
       (pnorm(beta, mu, sigma) - pnorm(alpha, mu, sigma)))

  sigma_trunc <- sigma^2 * (1 + 
       ((alpha*dnorm(alpha, mu, sigma) - beta*dnorm(beta, mu, sigma))
        / (pnorm(beta, mu, sigma) - pnorm(alpha, mu, sigma))) -
       ((dnorm(alpha, mu, sigma) - dnorm(beta, mu, sigma)) 
        / (pnorm(beta, mu, sigma) - pnorm(alpha, mu, sigma)))^2)

  return(c(mu_trunc, sigma_trunc))

}
```

Given `mu` and `sigma`, the function returns `mu_trunc` and `sigma_trunc`.

```
trunc_moments(c(0.25, 0.02), a=0, b=1)
```

Now, I would like to get the reverse results: given the function, `mu_trunc` and `sigma_trunc`, can I obtain the values of `mu` and `sigma` ?

I tried something with nleqslv R package but I am not sure this is what I am looking for.

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(c(0.25, 0.0004), trunc_moments, a = 0, b = 1)$x
```

Comment: The call pf `trunc_moments` gives an error message. It should be: `trunc_moments(c(0.25, 0.02), a=0, b=1)` since `trunc_moments` expects a vector for the argument `moments`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that takes the output of your `trunc_moments` and calculates the required input to `trunc_moments`. You can do this like so:

```
trunc_inverse <- function(minput,a,b) {

    temp <- trunc_moments(minput,a,b)
    y <- c(0.25,0.02) - temp
    y
}
```

`minput` is the result of `trunc_moments` for a given input passed in argument `moments` to the function `trunc_moments`.
The return value of `trunc_inverse` after solving should be the original input.  But there is a problem.

If you do this:

```
nleqslv(c(0.25, 0.0004), trunc_inverse, a=0, b=1)
```

a part of the output is

```
$x
[1] 0.2500000 0.1414214
```

which is NOT your original input.

If you insert these values in a call of `trunc_moments` like this

```
trunc_moments(c(0.25,0.1414214),a=0,b=1)
```

the result is

```
[1] 0.25000000 0.02000001
```

So your original function give the same output for different combinations of the `moments` input. This implies that your function `trunc_moments` will give the same output for different inputs.

You have some work to do.